# Generic Functional Interfaces Simple example using Consumer

Tags: java, generics, functional-interface

I am trying to write a generic method that accepts a functional interface. See example. Any help appreciated.

UPDATED: Have it compiling and running. Interested in comments or suggestions for improvement or clarification.

I will not be creating a Typed Abstract Base Class.  Adding an additional parameter to the repeat method specifying which robot to execute the command on seems more consistent with other similar examples.

Thoughts?

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

/**
 * The intent is to create a generic function repeat() in the Robot base class
 * that will repeat actions for all subclasses of robots
 */
public class GenericFunctionalInterface
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Consumer<Robot> actionTurn = Robot::turnLeft;
        // Consumer<EnhancedRobot> anyAction = EnhancedRobot::anyAction;

        Robot r = new Robot();
        r.repeat(3, a->a.turnLeft() );

        EnhancedRobot e = new EnhancedRobot();
        e.repeat(3, a->a.anyAction() ); // cannot find symbol - method anyAction()
        // if ((EnhancedRobot)a).anyAction() is used this works
    }
}

class Robot 
{
    public void move() { System.out.println("MOVE"); }

    public void turnLeft() { System.out.println("TURNLEFT"); }

    public <T extends Robot> void repeat(int n, Consumer<T> cmd )
    {
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) cmd.accept( (T) this); // UPDATED: casting this to T removed -> incompatible types: Robot cannot be converted to T
        // this will be whatever type repeat is called on
    } 

    // added this override - specifying what robot to send the command to
    public <T extends Robot> void repeat(int n, Consumer<T> cmd, T robot )
    {
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) cmd.accept( robot );
    } 

}

class EnhancedRobot extends Robot
{
    public void turnRight() { System.out.println("TURNRIGHT"); }

    public void move() {  System.out.println("MOVEOVERIDE"); }

    public void anyAction() { System.out.println("ANYACTION"); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the `e.repeat()` problem: Suppose you have this code:

```
class SuperRobot extends Robot {}

EnhancedRobot e = new EnhancedRobot();
e.repeat(3, new Consumer<SuperRobot>() {
  @Override
  public void accept(SuperRobot t) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Then inside the repeat method you want to call:

```
Consumer<T> cmd;
cmd.accept(this);
```

This would fail, because `this` is of `EnhancedRobot` type, but `cmd` expects to get a `SuperRobot`. That's why you cannot call it there.

The `a.anyAction()` problem is there because `a` is of type `Robot` which doesn't have the `anyAction()` method. From the declaration (`T extends Robot`), the only safe assumption about its type is that is a `Robot` or something that extends it. So you cannot call a method from `EnhancedRobot` on it.

Comment: OK. If I understand you correctly, this should work:

    public <T extends Robot> void repeat(int n, Consumer<T> cmd, T robot )
    {
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) cmd.accept( robot ); 
    }

usage:

        e.repeat(3, a->a.anyAction(), e );

Comment: Yes, that would work since you declare the `Consumer` and the `robot` to have the same type. You could make the method static, since it works with another `Robot` instance.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to parameterise `Robot` with the type of `Consumer`s it will accept, in the manner of `Enum`, and add a method that returns an appropriately typed `this` (which requires `Robot` to be abstract, as any default implementation would have to incorrectly return `null`).

```
abstract class Robot<THIS extends Robot<THIS>> {
    ...
    public void repeat(int n, Consumer<THIS> cmd) {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            cmd.accept(getThis());
        }
    }    
    protected abstract THIS getThis();
}

class EnhancedRobot extends Robot<EnhancedRobot> {
    @Override protected abstract EnhancedRobot getThis() {
        return this;
    }
    ...
}
```

Slightly more generally, I think you can declare `repeat` as

```
    public void repeat(int n, Consumer<? super THIS> cmd) {
```

Answer (score 0):

In your updated code, the `repeat` method doesn’t use the `Robot` instance you’re invoking the method on. So the method could be `static`.

```
// added this override - specifying what robot to send the command to
public static <T extends Robot> void repeat(int n, Consumer<T> cmd, T robot )
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) cmd.accept( robot );
}
```

to be invoked like

```
EnhancedRobot e = new EnhancedRobot();
Robot.repeat(3, a->a.anyAction(), e );
```

But even the `robot` parameter is not necessary for the `repeat` method. You could declare it as

```
public static void repeat(int n, Runnable cmd)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) cmd.run();
}
```

to be invoked like

```
EnhancedRobot e = new EnhancedRobot();
Robot.repeat(3, () -> e.anyAction());
```

which shows the actual problem of the design. Whether the action to repeat is related to a `Robot` instance or not, is irrelevant to the logic of the `repeat` method. Trying to enforce such a relationship via generic signatures creates problems without any benefit.

In fact, there are already generic tools allowing a repetition. E.g, you could write

```
EnhancedRobot e = new EnhancedRobot();
Collections.nCopies(3, e).forEach(EnhancedRobot::anyAction);
```

or

```
EnhancedRobot e = new EnhancedRobot();
IntStream.range(0, 3).forEach(i -> e.anyAction());
```